# How to list subdirectory in the same order of date of creation with Python 2.7 under Linux?

Tags: python

I have subdirectory 'f' under base_path.
My python Skript is creating 5 Directory after each other under "base_path". example like this ('a','b','c','d','e').  So now I have under base_path one old Directory ('f') and 5 new Directory ('a','b','c','d','e'). 
I listed the new with:

```
os.chdir(base_path)

for i in range (5):
    dirs = [os.path.join(os.getcwd(),d) for d in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if ((os.path.isdir(d)) and 'f' not in d)]

    print dirs
```

I have a list like

```
['e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

but i want a function that append every new created Directory to have:

```
[ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

In the same order of their date of creation.

Note: it worked with 4 Directory but with 5 Directory no.

Comment: Try replacing `os.listdir(os.getcwd())` with `sorted(os.listdir(os.getcwd()), key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), x)))`

Comment: Thank you :) it worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sort the files returned by `os.listdir()` into modified time order. This can be done by sorting on the value returned by `os.path.getmtime()` for each file as follows:

```
os.chdir(base_path)

for i in range (5):
    dirs = [os.path.join(os.getcwd(),d) for d in sorted(os.listdir(os.getcwd()), key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), x))) if ((os.path.isdir(d)) and 'f' not in d)]

    print dirs
```